# MySQL Update Order Issue?

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to toggle a status field and based on the toggled status field set a string.  What I've got works fine if I'm on my development machine running MySQL 5.6.38 but does not work on production which is running MySQL 5.5.53 (AWS RDS).  By not working I mean the `status` field gets toggled but the `a_string` field is ALWAYS the string "string2".  If I run the SQL on development I can pass an individual row id or an array of ids and it just works.  On production it works if I pass a single row id but not if I pass multiple rows.  The SQL I'm using is:

```
UPDATE table1 c
LEFT JOIN table2 t ON t.id = c.a_id
LEFT JOIN table3 e ON e.id = t.b_id
LEFT JOIN table4 s ON s.c_id = c.id
SET s.`status` = IF(s.`status` = '2', '0', '2'),
s.a_string = IF(s.`status` = '2', 'string1', 'string2'),
s.timestamp = NOW() WHERE s.id IN(?,?,?,?,?)
```

I don't know if it makes any difference but the `status` field is a MySQL `SET` type.  I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable at SQL can point out what I'm missing.

Comment: this question is very unlikely to answer without looking into data. If query works on one env, then it will work on other env as well

Comment: Yea I get that.  I'm not sure how I can help though.  I've spent many hours looking at the data and the best I can tell is that MySQL changed when the update happens between 5.5 and 5.6 (or it's a setting) so the second `IF` that tests the, in theory, newly updated status is testing it after the update in 5.6 and on 5.5 it's testing before the update.  I can paste some of the data but I'm not sure it's helpful without a LOT more context.